# iOS: Is it possible to send audio out both headphones and speakers at the same time?

Tags: ios, audio, speaker, headphones

We're looking to send some serial data out from the headphone jack, but would like to still be able to play audio from the speakers. Is it possible to send output to both? If so, is it possible to send different audio to each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I'm aware. You can get programatic notification of when the routing has changed (i.e. when someone connects a headphone cable), but you are unable to specify which device(s) to use for output.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking too. However, the alarm app for example plays the alarm sound out of both headphones (if plugged in) as well as the speaker at the same time. So I'm curious if apple is using an undocumented API or if all of us have access to that.

Comment: It's likely that Apple is using a private API. Wouldn't be the first time.